# Unit test case for Domain class ( testing constraints) - Grails

Tags: grails, spock

I am actually new in the world of Grails. I am trying to write a test case for domain class which is having some constraints . I am getting a Null pointer exception on my object when i am trying to run my unit test. On debugging I got to know that there is something fishy with my toString method which is causing the object to set as Null. How should I move ahead ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is my domain class:

```
@MultiTenant

class OrderCharge {
    static scaffold = [
        exclude: ['tenantId'],
    ]

    static belongsTo = [
        order: SalesOrder
    ]

    MiscOrderCharges miscOrderCharges
    Date lastUpdated
    double quantity
    double price
    SapInvoiceRecord sapInvoice

    static constraints = {
        order(nullable: true)
        quantity(min:1d)
        miscOrderCharges()
        sapInvoice(nullable: true)
    }

    String toString(){
        def pattern = "\$##,###.00"
        def currency = new DecimalFormat(pattern)
        String rate = currency.format(miscOrderCharges.price)
        return "$miscOrderCharges x$quantity"
    }
}
```

Here is my Unit test case:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Unroll
import spock.lang.Specification
@TestFor(OrderCharge)
//@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)

class ChargeSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        mockForConstraintsTests(
            OrderCharge, [
                new OrderCharge(order: Mock(SalesOrder),
                    miscOrderCharges: Mock(MiscOrderCharges),
                    quantity: 1.0,
                    price:20.0
                        /*, sapInvoice: Mock(SapInvoiceRecord) */
                )
            ]
        )
    }

    void validateConstraints(obj, field, error) {
        def validated = obj.validate()
        if (error && error != 'valid') {
            assert !validated
            assert obj.errors[field]
            assert error == obj.errors[field]
        } else {
            assert !obj.errors[field]
        }
    }

    @Unroll("test inventory all constraints #field is #error")
    def "test Charge all constraints"() {
        given:
        def obj = new OrderCharge("$field": val)

        expect:
        validateConstraints(obj, field, error)

        where:
        error               |field                 |val
        'nullable'          |'orderCharge'         |null
        'nullable'          |'sapInvoice'          |null
        'min'               |'quantity'            |-1
        'min'               |'price'               |0
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumps out at me is your return in the toString().

```
    return "$miscOrderCharges x$quantity"
```

You're using gStrings there.  It's my understanding that individual variables can be referred to using simple $ notation, as in the format *$somevariable*, whereas expressions are in the format *${expression}*.

In your statement **x$quantity** seems like a typo.  Did you mean to multiply them as an expression like below?

```
    return "${miscOrderCharges * quantity}"
```

See http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString.html for more information.

Comment: yeah , they need to be multiplied , and I have used astrisk(*) for multiplication but still can't get it passed. Thanks for your reply though. Appreciate it .